# loop a number from 0-9 and form a square

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to loop a number from 0-9 base on the user's input. And form a square inside a table, using those numbers. Here's my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        var x = $("#input").val(); 
        $("td").each(function(index,value){
            if(index < x){
                $(this).text(index);
            }
            $(this).find("td:last").addClass("last");
                $(this).find("td").each(function() {
                   if ($(this).hasClass("last")) {
                       for(var y = $(".last"); y < 9; y ++ ){
                           alert(y);
                       }
                      // this is the last column
                   } 
            });
        });

        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/newluj/0g4mj85p/14/

Comment: Your question should be more elaborative. Would be great if you could add some output diagrams etc.

Comment: I do not understand the question, for example;                                                   If value is equal to 1:
1

If value is equal to 3: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 Is correct?

Comment: If I input a value of 5, the output should be like this. http://jsfiddle.net/newluj/5ovqn5nk/